# Разбить текст на буквы в массив с++

Tags: c++

Мне нужно разбить текст на массив с буквами.
Например: **Привет я работник.** ->
vector  array = {П, р, и, в, е, т, ,я, ,р,а,б,о,т,н,и,к,.}

Comment: `std::string st = "test"; std::vector<char> vect(st.cbegin(), st.cend());`

Comment: Если на ваш вопрос ответили - не забудьте отметить галочкой и жмякнуть на стрелку вверх

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    string text = "Привет я работник.";
    vector<char> res;

    for (auto& i : text)
    {
        res.push_back(i);       
    }
 
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: В самом деле, зачем просто - `vector<char> res(text.begin(),text.end());` - если можно сложно?... :)

Answer (score 2):

Тебе нужно всего то крутить цикл по длине строки, и в массив складывать каждую букву, и вывести.
Для длины строки:strlen(Твоя строка)
Цикл используй For